# Installing Ubuntu on Win 8 Tablet

Tags: system-installation, uefi, intel, tablet

I know this may seem a little bit duplicated, but my problem is more worse. It's like this:

I have got a Win 8 tablet pc, which uses **EFI** boot option instead of **UEFI**. But what make it worse is that it seems like the tablet doesn't support USB boot options. It just doesn't have this module when you go into boot menu and select it.

And, as well suggested by most articles, **wubi** should not be used. As a matter of fact, I've tried every way I can get and failed.

After all, I just hate Windows and want to install a **Ubuntu** on it, whether it's *Desktop* or *Touch*. Can anyone tell me some possible approaches, or should I just give up? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing and running Linux on this device is a challenging task. It would require  intermediate to advanced knowledge in Linux.

This is because the Linux kernel shipped with Ubuntu Desktop doesn't entirely support the hardware(It's made for Desktops!), and so many non-critical hardware like WiFi, Audio, Webcam may not work. Still it's possible. But the ultimate solution

Hence you will have to try third-party kernel modules, find and install opensource drivers for not-working hardware manually, test different kernels etc. to get the entire system working.

That being said, [here](https://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/linux_lenovo_miix3/) is a good guide which will get you going. Some excerpts from the page which answers your question:

You need to boot Ubuntu USB on the device. As mentioned in the above page, this computer has a UEFI firmware without legacy mode emulation (or disabled). What we will do is to load grub on the device and manually boot Ubuntu from it. Fot this, you will need a externally powered USB hub, and two flash drives, one with the boot loader and other with Ubuntu.

1. Go to the UEFI menu and Disable Secure boot. To make a bootable USB stick, format the other USB drive in MBR format  with a single FAT32/LBA partition (type 0x0C) and put the bootloader as `EFI/boot/bootia32.efi`.
2. Generate the grub image with the modules specified in the guide.
3. Boot into the USB and GRUB should load.
4. Now manually boot into the Ubuntu USB from the grub command line. [Here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) is a good webpage describing the process.

Comment: Thanks for a reference. That's somehow close to what I'm looking for. But the USB is really a **big** problem, even it has a USB boot option for me to choose, it **doesn't** have the module! Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Chromium as SaxDaddy suggested, it would be a good learning experience. After you manage to boot from USB, whenever you are stuck, you could always post your specific issue here as a question and hopefully you will get a solution.  What do you mean "it doesn't have a module!"

Comment: When I go to boot menu, it only has a option called "Windows Boot Manager". When I try to select the USB option from the advanced menu(it has _a lot_ of options), it told me that it doesn't have the option of booting from USB. Hope you understand that.

Comment: By the way, I have upgrade it to Win 10 now, but I still don't find an option to boot from USB. Someone said that the problem is that my Windows edition is not the _professional edition_.

Answer (score 1):

### Fair Warning.

You don't identify the 'Win 8' tablet.

*It may not even be possible for the brand/model you are using.*

---

**For 'HP Stream 7' and 'HP Stream 8':** (basically twins)

Most of the information you need is here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/review/R21XA8UO4RTHR2/ref=cm_cr_pr_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00NSHLVD2

He also has a blog which goes into more detail, (but read both carefully): http://www.kyledavidson.ca/blog/2015/3/15/booting-linux-on-32bit-uefi-devices-hp-stream-7

Comment: Why is "dont identify the Win 8 tablet"?

Comment: Well the two links _does_ seem to help, but it seems like that my tablet just dont have the option to do so.

Comment: What I meant was: ***What brand/model of 8-inch 'Windows' tablet?**

Comment: First, I just meant that it is a *Windows 8* tablet...



Second, it is a Lenovo Miix 3 tablet.

Comment: Well I know it may not have possible approaches to this on my tablet. But is there any official or community documentation about flashing _ubuntu touch_ on tablets? @david6